# URL to individual email

Tags: macos, email, url

Is it possible to have an url that links to an individual email message on my local machine? So that if I click on `osxmail://759847982` my mail client will open that specific message.

GMail can do this, but I wonder if it's possible in a native client.

I'm open to any application, it doesn't have to be Apple Mail.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply drag the message from Mail.app to a folder to create the link you want. The link that is generated is automagically named using the subject line of the email message. Yes, there are many such situations where Mac OS will do the *natural* thing.

You can also drag any message to TextEdit.app (as long as it's to an RTF document).  Sadly, I haven't gotten this to work with Pages '09, but TextEdit isn't that bad.  The same is reported to work with Stickies. See [this link](http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/link-to-mail-messages-in-stickes.php) for a stickies example.

Here is another approach:

In Mail.app, on the message that you'd like to link to, select

```
View->Message->All Headers
```

(or <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>)

and look for the a line that begins with *Message ID*.  Copy the text to the right of "Message ID" and use it to link to that message via

```
message://<copied-messageid>
```

.  Make sure to copy the `<` and `>` along with the rest of the id. I've tested this and it works with Safari.app as described in [this article](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071118154803739) on MacOSX Hints.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I honestly didn't think it would be possible, just threw it up because "you never know..."

Comment: ... which brings me to my [next question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/54981/769). Any ideas?

Comment: @MichieldeMare, I've posted an answer there as well :D  Enjoy.

Comment: to make it work in todoist I needed to replace < by %3C and > by %3E (urlencoded), then it works, amazing, didn't think this is possible!

Answer (score 0):

> I'm open to any application, it doesn't have to be Apple Mail.

I have used [Airmail](http://airmailapp.com) in the past which has this functionality.

I don't have it installed anymore (the iOS app was full of bugs and got on my nerves so I'm back to Mail.app) but it was somewhere in the menu bar (search for "copy link").